# Letting the main navigation stretch across the whole wrapper

Tags: css, wordpress

The CSS for [this page](http://sheldonblk.com/) is below:

```
#main_nav ul, #main_nav ul li, #main_nav ul ul { list-style: none; margin:0; padding: 0; }
#main_nav ul { position: relative; z-index: 597; float: left; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
#main_nav ul li {  float: left; line-height: 1.8em; vertical-align: middle; text-transform:uppercase; }
#main_nav ul li.hover, #main_nav ul li:hover { position: relative; z-index: 599; cursor: default; }
#main_nav ul ul { visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0; z-index: 598; width: 100%;}
#main_nav ul ul li { float: none; font-size:12px; }
#main_nav ul ul ul { top: 0; left: 99%; }
#main_nav ul li:hover > ul { visibility: visible; display:block; }
```

How can I make the navigation buttons stretch across the whole outer wrapper where it says "media, community, etc.."?

Comment: Time to start using capital letters and punctuation. You're a grown man! :)

Comment: the only reason you like capitals and punctuation is because someone told you to like it when you were a boy

Comment: That, or because it's a basic sign of respect to people from whom you're expecting free time, assistance and expertise. You know, in some circles, this sort of knowledge comes for a steep fee. Perhaps it's time you began to count your frakking chickens, son.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the width of your `#main_nav ul` div to 100% and set your list menu items, `#main_nav ul li`, to expand equally, so 100/8 = 12.5% each.

Comment: thank you , worked fine :-)..  but now as i hover over the items a line appears beside the drop down menu... also.. is there any easy css function to center the words inside the box's?  thanks :)

Comment: Easy, to center your list items inside just add "text-align:center" to your **#main_nav ul li a** declaration in your css and to eliminate the line from the drop down just remove the border-right:... style from your **#main_nav ul ul** declaration, or adjust the width of your submenu to something like 121px.

Comment: thank you - you are a master.. just wondering where u see border-right

Comment: okay so i found border-right and removed it but it still shows ? :(  also is there any reason why things are off just a smidge?  ex. the very right of the words 'contact us'

Comment: border-right:.. is set in line 272 of your 1-default.css sheet for that element.

Comment: Hmm, for some reason your 1-default.css sheet is being loaded twice, so its appearing in both sheets. About the width of your submenu being off, you have to also compensate for the borders, they add to the width of your items, so just add a width to your submenu items, you can add "width:120px" to your **#main_nav ul li ul li** declaration and that should do the trick..or just remove the borders being applied to the left and right of your submenu.